# Tool that outputs the longest chain of calls

Tags: static-analysis, call-graph

**The context**: I am carrying out the analysis procedure described here: [approach](http://almossawi.com/firefox/prose/).

**The blocking point** is finding the "longest chain of calls" for the project under observation.  What tool can be used for finding this?  I presume it will be a static analysis tool.

Otherwise, I presume a call graph generator can be used for this purpose.  But then, how to infer the longest chain of calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "longest" call chain in terms of hops is straightforward to determine from a call graph.  This assumes you have acquired one, and yes this generally requires static analysis.  (You can get a dynamically-generated call graph, but it likely won't exhibit all possible calls). Acquiring one for firefox, with function calls that cross language boundaries, if you want to take those into account, may be pretty challenging.

Given such a call graph: 
Start with the call graph with blank call-path-length values for each node.  Mark the root(s) [your call graph may be a DAG] with the call-path-length value 0.   For each unlabelled child, for which all parents have been determined, label that child with the max of the values from parents, plus 1.  Repeat until all children are labelled.  [If you have a cycle in the call graph,  you have to decide to ignore it, or treat it as some constant addition to the path length.]  The longest path is easily extracted by starting with the highest-value node, and walking backwards to the most expensive parents until a root is reached.

[EDIT] if you back propagate leaf values to parents, you can end up with the graph with every node labelled as to how far it reaches.

Are you sure you want longest-chain?  Or do you want Worst Case Execution time?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I want to follow the approach described in the [article](http://almossawi.com/firefox/prose/).  At one point, they say "With the Firefox codebase, the longest chain of calls is seven calls, hence no file that is connected to another is more than seven calls away.".   I understand from this that I have to find the longest chain for my project that I want to analyze.

Comment: That "approach" suggests that somebody extracted *direct* calls from the calls.   If you use C or C++, that's laughably naive; indirect calls are very important and not so easily extracted.  The matrix approach to computing "a calls b" indirectly finds out how far each function can reach on each iteration; the algorithm I described above does the same thing but leaves each function marked effectively with its "call span".

Comment: By _indirect_ calls you mean calls that bind at runtime?  Then a dynamic analyzer would be needed for this task?

Comment: Yes, more precisely, any call that is made through a pointer.   You could do this with a dynamic analyzer at the risk of missing some calls because you didn't exercise them.  You could do this better through a static analyzer.  Is Mozilla code in C or C++?

Comment: Actually, my project is in Java.  The authors of that article have used Mozilla as support, and I follow just the approach.  Actually now I have to find a tool to get me the call graph in a text file or something, and then read this in memory to apply your algorithm and find the answer.

Comment: Ok, then "indirect calls" means calls on specific methods in specific classes.